# Vim is opening with Vi when I use Sudo - why?

Tags: sudo, vim, 22.04

I use neovim. I changed my .zshrc to open nvim when I type `vim` in the terminal.

My configuration is from my Mac where I didn't use Sudo much (now I use Ubuntu, I use sudo all the time).

When I do `sudo vim {anything}`, Vi opens or it might be Vim but its not neovim.

In my zshrc I have:

```
alias vim="nvim"
EXPORT EDITOR="nvim"
```

How do I activate nvim to open files when I use `sudo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `sudo vim` opens `vim` is because `vim` on your system is set to open `vim.basic` through the Debian alternatives system. You override this for your personal user with an alias, but `sudo` does not use your user configuration, but the configuration of user `root`.

Rather than also setting up an alias for the root user, you better set up your system so `vim` points to `nvim`:

Execute the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vim
```

Select the option listing `nvim` (`/usr/bin/nvim`):

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative vim (providing /usr/bin/vim).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/nvim        30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

In this case, I would enter `2`.

After this, you can remove your alias definition.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `sudo`, you start another shell session under a different user (root). Aliases and environment variables defined in your previous shell are not passed to that second shell.

You can pass environment variables using `sudo -E` (or, even better, specifying a particular variable(s) to pass instead of the entire environment: `sudo --preserve-env=EDITOR`), but there seems to be no way to pass the aliases. You must define again the alias for `vim` in root's `.zshrc` file.

Comment: I see. I suppose that also means for me to have all my nvim setup in sudo, id also need to have a separate config setup for nvim with root too?

Comment: `sudo` doesn't  execute a shell (unless you pass the -s option or you actually run a shell with it) so editing `.zshrc` or other shell config is useless. I'd suggest writing a script that executes nvim instead and adding that to root's PATH or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sudo vim {anything}`, consider using `sudoedit {anything}` or `sudo -e {anything}`

`sudo` will then use the editor defined in your user's `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables. You can also define a `SUDO_EDITOR` variable if you want a different editor specifically for `sudo`.